# pgAdmin 4 server configuration tool

Tags: pgadmin-4

In pgAdmin 3, I was able to customize the server configuration (.config) by:

```
Tools -> Server configuration -> postgresql.config -> change parameters -> reload server
```

Although I've searched and researched, I am not able to do this in pgAdmin 4 (v1.5). Any help would be very useful as I really need to fine tune PG.

Comment: This feature has been removed from pgAdmin4, you have to do it manually.

Comment: you mean just editing the postgresql.conf? does this automatically update the server configuration? Thanks a lot!

Comment: After changing the postgresql.conf, you need to restart PG service.

Comment: No, you just need to click "Tools" -> "Reload configuration" (for most params). Anyway it's unreasonable that they removed the edit functionality from pgAdmin.

Comment: Where is located `postgresql.conf` for pgAdmin 4?

Comment: @MatteoGuarnerio in the "data" directory (same location as `pgèhba.conf`).

Answer (score 2):

To summarize the comments and my own experience: that feature has not been ported back to pgAdmin4 (which is the reason I'm rolling back to pgAdmin3: editing the `pg_hba.conf` is useful for our customer's admins. Unfortunately, pgAdmin3 is compatible with PostgreSQL 9.5 only).

But you still have the "Reload" option in the menu "*Tools > Reload Configuration*", that you can use after you manually-edited either `postgresql.conf` or `pg_hba.conf`. You have to select the Server node to get that option enabled.

Answer (score -1):

Reload the configuration

Option 1: From the command-line shell

```
su - postgres
/usr/bin/pg_ctl reload
```

Option 2: Using SQL

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

see http://www.heatware.net/databases/postgresql-reload-config-without-restarting/

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP question

Comment: He asked, among other things, how to reload server configuration if pgadmin3 is not available. In the comment of 22 Jul he asked that again. So I answered that part.

Comment: Yes, but that's the only functionality that has NOT been removed in pgAdmin 4, so why on earth shouldn't he use the UI?